# pass data to another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

i have a list of users on the app getting them from Parse.com

what i want to do is:

1. click on user name
2. take me to a page to display the clicked user profile

for now i success getting the clicked user id BUT i didn't find how to

pass the clicked user id to the profile fragment

here is the click code

```
protected OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {

                        ParseObject friend = mFriends.get(position);
                        String friendId = friend.getObjectId();


                         ////////I want something here take me to 
                         ////////the user profile fragment and show 
                        /////the user profile information's using the ID (friendId)

                            Log.d("Clicked item id", " "+ friendId); 

                    }
                };
```

the code is simple just want to pass this id (friendId) to the fragment (ViewProfileActivity.java) and start the activity

Comment: Are those two fragments inside the same activity?

Comment: No the other fragment called ViewProfileActivity.java

Comment: Then send them as extras to the intent that opens the second activity, then you can use inside the second fragment:

    `getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra();`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

inside your fragment:

```
public static Fragment newInstance(String friendId) 
{
     MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
     bundle.putString("friend_id", friendId);
     frag.setArguments(bundle);
     return frag;
}
```

and then you can retreive this bundle in the `onCreate()` method of your fragment using **getArguments()** .

Comment: could you edit your answer to make it fit my code and insert it into my question ?

Comment: No I'm not going to write your program for you

Answer (score 1):

send them as extras to the intent that opens the second activity, then you can use the following inside the second fragment:

```
 getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra();
```